# agregar atributo a componente input con stencil.js

Tags: angular, ionic4, web-components

estoy armando componentes web con *stencil.js* y trabajo en este momento con la creación de un input para formularios, el tema es que tengo que agregarle el atributo formControlName="", para poder exportarlo a un proyecto con Angular. El tema es que no logro pasarle este atributo al componente que genero:

```
import { Component, Host, h, Prop, State } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'input-text',
  styleUrl: 'inputext.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class Inputext {
  @Prop({ reflectToAttr: true })
  disabled: boolean;
  @Prop() value: string;
  @Prop() maxlength: number;
  @Prop() minlength: number;
  @Prop() title: string;
  @Prop() placeholder: string;
  @Prop() type: string;
  @Prop() formcontrolname: string;
  @State() formControlName: string;

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <label>{this.title}</label>
        <input type={this.type}
          placeholder={this.placeholder}
          formControlName={this.formcontrolname}
          value={this.value} maxlength={this.maxlength}
          minlength={this.minlength}
          disabled={this.disabled} />
      </Host>
    );
  }

}
```

y este es el componente en el html:

```
<input-text type="text" title="First Input" formControlName="numerosPrimos" placeholder="Holo" maxlength="12"></input-text>
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, lo mejor es que le coloques un id a tu elemento generado y mediante Javascript con el metodo setAttribute() le coloques el atributo. Ejemplo:

```
<ion-label>Principal</ion-label>
let bt = document.getElementById("lkbuton");

bt.setAttribute("[routerLink]","['/']");
console.log(bt);

result = <ion-label [routerLink]="['/']" >Principal</ion-label>
```